# Do we need to manage the state of radio buttons in Elm?

Tags: elm

I am referring to this example in http://elm-lang.org/examples/radio-buttons. I don't see anywhere whereby the state of the buttons is being managed.

In my own little Elm project I need to do something like

```
label []
    [ input
        [ type_ "radio"
        , checked (model.choosenSize == size)
        , onClick (SetSize size)
        ] []
    , text (sizeToString size)
    ]
```

Without managing the `checked` attribute, all the radio buttons will remain checked after you click on it.

So what is the magic in the example?

Comment: If you add a `name` attribute to all of the 'grouped' radio elements, your web browser will only allow one to be selected at a time. You can achieve the same thing in Elm by managing the 'checked' state in your model. However, if you don't manage their state in Elm, Elm has no way of 'reading' which one is currently active.

Answer (score 3):

The example you are referring is very simple. It doesn't explicitly manage the state of the buttons. Instead, their state is managed by the browser. In a real application, of course, you would better manage it explicitly. Something like:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ fieldset []
        [ radio "Small" (model.fontSize == Small) (SwitchTo Small)
        , radio "Medium" (model.fontSize == Medium) (SwitchTo Medium)
        , radio "Large" (model.fontSize == Large) (SwitchTo Large)
        ]
    , Markdown.toHtml [ sizeToStyle model.fontSize ] model.content
    ]


radio : String -> Bool -> msg -> Html msg
radio value isChecked msg =
  label
    [ style [("padding", "20px")]
    ]
    [ input [ type_ "radio", checked isChecked, name "font-size", onClick msg ] []
    , text value
    ]
```

(I added a `Bool` argument to `radio`)